# Allow parameter to have more than one value? for example value 1|| value 2 (C#,Light switch)

Tags: c#, parameter-passing, visual-studio-lightswitch, optional-parameters

in my project "Light switch C#", I have a button which take me to a certain screen. The screen take one parameter of type string, for example "Office-Italy","Office- Germany"

My code:

```
enter code here
   partial void HQ_Execute()
    {
        // Write your code here.
        this.Application.ShowPart_1_SearchBalanceGreaterZero("IC-MOS");

    }
```

now the question here is, I have 12 office and when I press the HQ (Head office)  button I want my filter to be something like *. in other words I want my filter to have this value

```
this.Application.ShowPart_1_SearchBalanceGreaterZero("IC-MOS"||"IC-IT")
```

is this possible by anyhow?

Thanks a lot,
Zayed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a parameter can't have more than one value. So you'll need to change your method to accommodate what you need, e.g. by changing the parameter so that it's a *collection* of strings instead of a single string.

You *could* change the implementation instead, e.g. to allow you to pass "IC-MOS,IC-IT" and split it by commas - but it's clearer (IMO) to specify the values separately.

Comment: @ Jon: Thanks for your reply. Ok , I totally get your idea. but is there is another way to say deactivate this filter from code. something like if I press the HQ button give me back the query results as if the "Office Filter" does not exist?

Comment: @Zayed: Well you'd need to *implement* that functionality - either with a different method which didn't take any filters, or in the existing method, specifying that if you passed in an empty list, that meant "all". It's hard to answer you more concretely without more details - it boils down to "Yes, you need to implement that."

Comment: @ Jon:FYI:  I implemented your solution, the only problem is that is take like extra 10 sec for the results to come out. I guess this means that the filter is causing this delay.

Answer (score 0):

Other than what have been already mentioned in Jon's answer; you can pass your value as a single string and in destination method break and parse them accordingly. Something like

```
this.Application.ShowPart_1_SearchBalanceGreaterZero("IC-MOS|IC-IT")
```

In your method body

```
void ShowPart_1_SearchBalanceGreaterZero(string data)
{
  string[] strarr = data.Split('|');

  //now use the data string array the way you want
}
```

Comment: Isn't that what my second paragraph is saying, just using | instead of comma?